# Android Intent to open CSV in spreadsheets

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a CSV file into google sheets, but I can't.

That's everything working fine, I can save my CSV to Google Drive and then open it from Drive, but I want to open it directly into Google Sheets.

Is that possible?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.getApplication(),
                activity.getApplication().getPackageName(), file);
        activity.getApplication().grantUriPermission(activity.getApplication().getPackageName(),
                contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setData(contentUri);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        shareIntent.setType("text/csv");

        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Abrir CSV"));
```

[I got only this options in intent chooser. I want Sheets here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4KDU.png)

Provider:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

xml/file_paths:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Um, get a job with Google, arrange to work on the Google Sheets team, and add the feature to Google Sheets to allow it to open CSV files, I guess.

Comment: It's possible to open CSV with sheets, I can do it like manually, by clicking with my finger on a csv file at my google drive :D

Comment: That does not mean that Google exposed that capability to third-party developers.

Answer (score 1):

Set the mime type to `text/*` and sheets should show up.

Also note that calling `setType` after `setData` will actually set the data to `null`